# R - Count Number of Occurrence Before Value

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, vector

I have a vector of Boolean variables (assume the following is a vector called vectorA):

```
TRUE
FALSE
FALSE
TRUE
FALSE
```

I want to count the number of occurrences of false prior to each false and return a vector. For the above list, the vector would look like:

```
0
1
2
2
3
```

If we convert the TRUE/FALSE to 0/1, this would be the same as summing the prior values. The table of

```
0
1
1
0
1
```

would return the same vector:

```
0
1
2
2
3
```

I know that I could use a for loop; something like

```
for (i in 1:length(vectorA))
    {if (i == 1)
        {0}
     elseif (vectorA[i])
        {vectorA[i-1]}
     else
        {vectorA[i-1] + 1}
     }
```

Is there any way to do this without a for loop? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
set.seed(124)
x <- sample(c(TRUE,FALSE),12,replace=TRUE)
##
R> x
 [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
##
R> cumsum(!x)
 [1] 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 5
```

Using your example vector,

```
R> y <- c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE)
R> cumsum(!y)
[1] 0 1 2 2 3
```